# UILabel with "+" text not centered vertically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

[image]

```
self.iconLabel.frame = self.contentView.frame;

self.iconLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:100.0];
self.iconLabel.text = @"+";
self.iconLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.iconLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

So the `UILabel`'s frame is the same size as its container view, self.contentView

I need the "+" to be centered vertically also, I want it in the center.

How can I achieve this?

My only notion is to shift the iconLabel.frame up.

EDIT: Changed from self.iconImageView to self.contentView which is a `UIView`. The `UILabel` is layered above the self.iconImageView which is a `UIImageView`.

EDIT 2: Tried implementing kshitij godara's code, the result is:

[image]

I altered the code slightly:

```
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height);

NSString *str = @"+";

UIFont *myFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:100.0];

CGSize stringSize = [str sizeWithFont:myFont constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

self.iconLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, stringSize.width, stringSize.height);
self.iconLabel.font = myFont;
self.iconLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
self.iconLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.iconLabel sizeToFit];
self.iconLabel.text = str;
```

EDIT 3:

the frame is quite large:

[image]

Comment: is iconLabel added as iconImageView's subview? If yes, use iconImageView.bounds instead of frame

Comment: I have a contentView which is a `UIView`. iconImageView is a `UIImageView`. Both iconImageView and iconLabel are in the contentView. I tried changing it from frame to bounds, did not change the result.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a problem of the font itself. Each font has defined it shapes, behavior, typesetting etc. The font seems to be positioning character "+" of the visual vertical center. You can test it on any other string containing letter "+", "dog+Cat" for example. The "+" letter will probably be drawn near bottom as it is on your image.

From my point of view, you have 2 options:

- Use icon image instead for the "+" sign. This will be simplest and the best working solution
- Use custom font edited to visually look exactly like you need (letter "+" totally centered in its typeset). This one would probably be very painfull and time-consuming option

Edit: Regarding 2nd option: I have already done such an procedure to fix some misaligned fonts following [this tutorial](http://www.andyyardley.com/2012/04/24/custom-ios-fonts-and-how-to-fix-the-vertical-position-problem/). However it still just fixes the whole font, not on a single character basis

Comment: Ya, if I replace the "+" with say "D", it fits as expected. I think the third option; shifting the `UILabel` up til looks like its centered will be the easiest solution. Thanks.

Comment: Using an image is really the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -- Try to apply this

```
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(iconImageFrame.size.width,1000.0f);

//Now Calculate size of string 

NSString *str = @"+";

//Always give the same font to calculate size which you giving for label 

UIFont *myFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:100.0];

CGSize stringSize = [str sizeWithFont:myFont 
                           constrainedToSize:constraint
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
//now set same font for uilabel and also make it to fit to size 
//like this

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myIconLabelFrame.x,myIconLabelFrame.y,stringSize.width,stringSize.height)];

myLabel.font = myFont;
myLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[myLabelsizeToFit];
myLabel.text = str;
```

As now label will be completely fit in size , therefore it will always be in center .This code also can be used for to increase height of label dynamically .
I hope it solve your problem .Thanks!

Comment: I implemented the code, and the text appears quite a bit further below where it should be. :-?

Comment: check by giving background color to uilabel , what size it is taking , is it actually fiting or not

Comment: Ok, changed the color and the label.frame.height is very tall.

Comment: also try to set fontsize small first check it by increasing continously

Comment: It narrows the frame but is still to tall.

Comment: what is narrowing frame small font, change constraint height to 50 first , then check the result

Comment: Yes, I make the font smaller and the label's frame narrows and height shrinks, but is still not he correct shape.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37547/discussion-between-kshitij-godara-and-log139)